# Is there any way to fix the horrendous toolbar icons after the Juno update?

Tags: eclipse, icons, alpha, antialiasing

At least on Windows 7, it looks like the title bar color may have been changed to blue.  However, the title bar icons were designed only to be used on a light gray bar rather than using alpha transparency for antialiasing.  Note the white highlights around the edge of the green circle "run" icon.

[image: Close up of hideous toolbar icons]

The icons look horrendous, like we're in 1995.  Is this how it appears on other Windows 7 user's installations as well?  I noticed there's theming, and the closest I can find to something that works is the olive theme.  I can't find a toolbar color in the Appearance/colors and fonts preferences though.  Is there any way to revert the title bar back to the old color or replace the icons with correctly designed ones?

In the meantime, I filed an [Eclipse bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=389288) for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either select the classic theme under Appearance (and restart!) to go back to the 3.x look or install the [Eclipse 4 Chrome theme](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-4-chrome-theme#.UE-BBYrN-4o), which can be tuned to your personal preferences in detail.

Comment: Ah, that did the trick--the restart was what I was missing.  I was wondering why some of the themes seemed to have no effect.  Why the hell don't they mention that you need to restart when you change the theme?

Comment: I just filed [another issue](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=389303) to suggest showing theme preview screen shots as well as offering a reboot.

Comment: Is there any way to replace these icons with a custom icon set?

Comment: No, the icons are part of the plugins providing them.