# Can I roll back my Eclipse Juno update?

Tags: eclipse, installation, updates, eclipse-juno

I don't recall the "install new updates" feature ever offering to perform a major release, certainly not without explaining that it's doing so like just happened with Juno.  I unintentionally updated and it appears to have done an in-place update.  This whole process is new behavior, right?

Is there any way to safely downgrade back to Indigo?

Comment: Eclipse won't update from from Helios to Indigo (or any major release) by itself, unless you add the release repo for that release.  But Juno has a special instruction that prevents upgrading from Indigo to Juno by accident.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Get a copy of Indigo and unzip it to a new directory.
- Add your other Eclipse plug-ins from their web sites.
- Zip up your newly created version of Indigo so you can restore it if you accidentally upgrade again.

Comment: I was afraid that was going to be the answer :(  Did Eclipse ever do this before?  (Offer to install a major release from the update manager)

Comment: @Jeff Axelrod: I don't know.  I only use the update manager to add external Eclipse plug-ins.  My development environment is too important to ever upgrade Eclipse.

Comment: Mine development environment is also too important to update--hence this question and follow-up comment.  I was expecting a minor Eclipse update, and was quite shocked and irritated to have it replaced with the [ugly](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12374463/403455) and [slow-as-hell](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=385272) Juno, without the option to roll back.

Comment: @Jeff Axelrod: Hopefully, your workspaces are still ok.  Otherwise, you'll have to recreate them as well.

Comment: Workspaces appear to be fine.  This is almost as bad as rebuilding a Windows machine.

Answer (score 4):

You can also go to `Help>About>Installation Details>Installation History`.  If you select a configuration prior to your last update, you can ask p2 to try and revert to that configuration (it will try and re-download any older plugins that have been deleted by the upgrade from the repositories available in the preferences).

Comment: Nope, still Juno.  Just a plugin rollback.  :(

Comment: There should be a number of previous entries.  Are they all Juno?

Comment: Sorry I was a bit terse.  I rolled back to a date well before I updated to Juno.  The platform didn't downgrade, only the plugins.  The snapshots must not be associated with a particular platform.